# PictureBox not changing the image

Tags: c#

I have a pictureBox that I use as a button. When I start the form I load it as disabled and after pressing a button I activate it, it works to change the image from disabled to activated. Then, when I disable this pictureBox again, the image doesn't change anymore ... what could be wrong?

here's my code:

```
private void btnUpdate_EnabledChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnUpdate.Enabled == true)
        {               
            if (mt.ArquivoExiste(Metodos.pathImagens, botaoUpdateNormal))
            {
                Image bt = Image.FromFile(Metodos.pathImagens + botaoUpdateNormal);
                btnUpdate.BackgroundImage = bt;
            }
        }
        else
        {                
            if (mt.ArquivoExiste(Metodos.pathImagens, botaoUpdateDisabled))
            {
                Image bt = Image.FromFile(Metodos.pathImagens + botaoUpdateDisabled);
                btnUpdate.BackgroundImage = bt;
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit:
I changed the string to make that easier and put the entire relationated code:

```
string botaoUpdateNormal = "btnUpdate_normal.png", botaoUpdateDisabled = "btnUpdate_disabled.png",
            botaoUpdateFocus = "btnUpdate_focus.png", botaoSearchNormal = "btnSearch_normal.png",
            botaoSearchFocus = "btnSearch_focus.png", botaoInsertNormal = "btnInsert_normal.png",
            botaoInsertFocus = "btnInsert_focus.png";
```

then i load the form:

```
private void IEstoque_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                
            if (mt.ArquivoExiste(Metodos.pathImagens, botaoUpdateDisabled))
            {
                Image bt = Image.FromFile(Metodos.pathImagens + botaoUpdateDisabled);
                btnUpdate.BackgroundImage = bt;
            }                
        }
```

After that I have an event that when I change the row of a grid, the btnUpdate activates, and when I click on it and update my dataBase it desactivates.

Comment: Is the `btnUpdate.BackgroundImage = bt;` line in the `else` block even getting hit?  Put a breakpoint there and let us know...

Comment: @Idle_Mind i put a breakpoint and it pass normally.

Comment: and what would 'normally' mean? Does it hit the code where the breakpoint is set? or does it not hit the code where the breakpoint is set ?

Comment: @Luuk it hit the code, pass into else's block and set the btnUpdate.BackgroundImage as 'bt'. But the image is not changed in form.

Comment: "Then, when I disable this pictureBox again, the image doesn't change anymore ... what could be wrong?"  Can you show us that code, then?  Are you creating a different instance of the form by chance?  Have some kind of loop preventing updates?  Other threads?  Etc...

Comment: You should debug your code, and check where `btnUpdate.Enabled` is changed.

Comment: @Idle_Mind i edit my question with more details. there is no loop.

Comment: @luuk it's enabled when i change a row of my grid and disabled when i click on btnUpdate.

Comment: Do not add words like "solved" to the title. See e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311829/why-does-stack-overflow-discourage-adding-solved-to-question-titles. If your question has been answered, accept the answer post that answered the question, or if no such post exists, add one yourself and accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it! before deactivating the button I called a form as follows: formname.Show ();
I just changed it to formname.ShowDialog (); and it worked normally.

Answer (score 0):

This code work for pictureBox "like button" and with separate button:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.pictureBox.Enabled = false;
            this.pictureBox.EnabledChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox_EnabledChanged);
            this.pictureBox.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox_MouseClick);
            this.button.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click);
            this.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Form1_MouseClick);
        }

        private void pictureBox_EnabledChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (pictureBox.Enabled == true)
            {
                var botao = "1.png";
                Image bt = Image.FromFile(botao);
                pictureBox.BackgroundImage = bt;
            }
            else
            {
                var botao = "2.png";
                Image bt = Image.FromFile(botao);
                pictureBox.BackgroundImage = bt;
            }
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox.Enabled = !pictureBox.Enabled;
        }
        
        private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!MouseIsPicture(e.Location)) return;
            TogglePicture();
        }

        private void pictureBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            TogglePicture();
        }

        private bool MouseIsPicture(Point location)
        {
            // Make sure the location is over the image.
            if (location.X < 0) return false;
            if (location.Y < 0) return false;
            if (location.X >= pictureBox.Width) return false;
            if (location.Y >= pictureBox.Height) return false;
            return true;
        }

        void TogglePicture()
        {
            pictureBox.Enabled = !pictureBox.Enabled;
        }
    }
```

More over: check if pictures you are loading are not the same

Comment: the pictures is not the same, and it not work. =/